# How to cache phpunit.phar on Travis CI?

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci, phar

At the moment I use Travis CI in order to test a Symfony Bundle. PHPUnit is installed by Composer since PHPUnit is declared as a `dev` dependency:

```
{
    …
    "require" : {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "symfony/symfony": "~2.7 || ~3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "~2.3",
        "liip/functional-test-bundle": "~1.4",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.* || ~5.1"
    },
    …
}
```

Even if I use Travis CI's cache to cache the `~/.composer` folder after each build, installing PHPUnit with Composer takes some time because PHPUnit has to check all the dependencies before installing them.

---

So I was thinking about **using the PHAR version of PHPUnit** that can be installed in one command:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
```

But if I use this command on Travis CI, PHPUnit will be downloaded once in each build. Is there a way to **cache this `phpunit.phar` file**? An easy way may be to put the file in the cache, check the date of this file and download a new version if the file is older than 1 day, but there may be a simpler solution.

There is `--self-update` option for PHPUnit but it [will be removed in the next major release](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2088).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Travis to keep certain directories between builds (called "caching" in their [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching)).

Simply add the following configuration to your Travis config file and the `/vendor` directory should persist across builds:

```
cache:
  directories:
    - vendor
```

You should still include a `composer install` call to your build to update dependencies when the `composer.json` file changed. To further speed up the `composer install` process, you can also add you `composer.lock` file to version control.

---

Alternatively, you can of course use the same feature to simple keep a downloaded `phpunit.phar` file between builds.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to indicate that I already use the Travis CI cache for Composer's cache.

Comment: Oh, I see. Why don't you just use it to cache your downloaded `phpunit.phar` file, too?

Comment: Because it would mean that Travis download the 2.9 Mb `phpunit.phar` file at every build.

Comment: You could check if it already exists, first: `[ -e cached/phpunit.phar ] || wget -O cached/phpunit.phar https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar`

Comment: How can I be sure that the lastest version of PHPUnit will be downloaded?